# Объясните пожалуйста задачу?

Tags: c#

Дана задача с таким условием как на скриншоте
[image: Условие задачи]

я начал шерстить интернет при каких условиях Х кривая принимает минимальное значение. я так понял при а > 0. при таком условии выполняется вычисление по формуле x = -b / 2a;
вообщем попробовал сделать вычисление

```
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            int x;
            
            if (a > 0)
            { 
              x = -b / 2 * a;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Impossible");
            }
            return a.ToString(); // так можно вернуть строковое представление числа

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, 2, 3));
            Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 3, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, -2, -3));
            Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(5, 2, 1));
            Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(4, 3, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 4, 5));

            // А в этих случаях решение существует:
            Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2) != "Impossible");
            Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 0) != "Impossible");
```

но в итоге ответ получается не тот который должен быть
[image: Вывод]

В ЧЕМ ПОДВОХ? ИЛИ ЧТО Я НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО ВЫЧИСЛЯЮ?

Comment: насколько я понял задание, нужно просто решить уравнение и вывести минимальное из решений, у вас в коде этого нет

Comment: `return a.ToString();` заменить на `return x.ToString();`

Comment: Пожалуйста если вам помог один из двух приведенный ответов, то примите его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же просто квадратное уравнение? Нужно найти вершину параболы? Вы считаете корни при условии, что дискриминант равен нулю, ок, допустим, но ваш код содержит ошибки:

- Что выведется в консоль при `a > 0`? У вас выводится `a`.
- Что выведется, если `a <= 0`, у вас выведется `Impossible`, а затем `a`, то есть сразу 2 строки. Угадайте, почему.

Вас учили использовать отладку, ставить точку останова? У вас есть Visual Studio? Вы же могли просто запустить и проверить пример локально с пошаговым выполнением кода? Это бы ответило на все ваши вопросы. [Отладка C# кода в Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).

А метод, должен выглядеть вот так.

```cs
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (a > 0 || b == 0)
    { 
        double x = (double)-b / (2 * a);
        return x.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "Impossible";
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня есть VS, но использовать отладку меня не учили. точнее объяснили как раз в видео уроке, после которого была эта задача, но я все же до конца не понял ее назначение. Изучать язык приходится самому. Найти хорошего ментора в Ташкенте сложно. У нас в основном преподают HTML, CSS, JS, Python.

Comment: а по поводу кода все равно полностью верный ответ не получается. вместо значений - 0.2 и - 0.375 выводятся нули, а в пункте 7 и 8 вместо True получается False.

Comment: @nikitasalnikov обновил ответ

Comment: а почему b==0, можете объяснить пожалуйста. что то я не догоняю. в методе Main при вызове GetMinX уже указаны же произвольные переменные a, b и c?

Comment: @nikitasalnikov как вы думаете, почему Impossible? Наверное потому что на ноль делить нельзя, так? А ноль на ноль делить можно, будет ноль.

Comment: понятно теперь. спасибо. придется математику вспоминать.

Answer (score 3):

1. Вы возвращаете `a.ToString()`, а нужно возвращать минимальное значение `x` (вершину параболы), то есть `return x.ToString()`
2. Вы пишите `x = -b / 2 * a` и сначала произойдет деление `-b / 2`, а потом умножение на `a`. А формула вершины параболы `x = -b / (2 * a)`
3. А ну и в теле `else` нужно вернуть `Impossible`, а не написать, а потом еще вернуть `a.ToString()`, чтобы напечатать еще одну строчку